# How to set image for button in Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7-beta3

I am receiving a "nil" error when trying to set the image for a button programmatically. What am I doing wrong? These are all not optionals.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var imageButton: UIButton!
var index: Int = 0

var images: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "image1.png")!, UIImage(named: "image2.png")!, UIImage(named: "image3.png")!, UIImage(named: "image4.png")!, UIImage(named: "image5.png")!, UIImage(named: "image6.png")!, UIImage(named: "image7.png")!, UIImage(named: "image8.png")!, UIImage(named: "image9.png")!, UIImage(named: "image10.png")!, UIImage(named: "image11.png")!, UIImage(named: "image12.png")!, UIImage(named: "image13.png")!, UIImage(named: "image14.png")!, UIImage(named: "image15.png")!, UIImage(named: "image16.png")!, UIImage(named: "image17.png")!, UIImage(named: "image18.png")!, UIImage(named: "image19.png")!, UIImage(named: "image20.png")!, UIImage(named: "image21.png")!, UIImage(named: "image22.png")!, UIImage(named: "image23.png")!, UIImage(named: "image24.png")!, UIImage(named: "image25.png")!, UIImage(named: "image26.png")!, UIImage(named: "image27.png")!, UIImage(named: "image28.png")!, UIImage(named: "image29.png")!, UIImage(named: "image30.png")!]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    //let screenHeight = screenSize.height

    let numWidth: CGFloat = 3
    let numHeight: CGFloat = 10
    self.scrollView.frame.size.width = screenWidth
    let width: CGFloat = (self.scrollView.frame.size.width - (numWidth + 1))/3

    for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 3; ++i{
        for var j:CGFloat = 0; j < 10; ++j {

            let image: UIImage = images[index] as UIImage!


            imageButton.setImage(image,forState:UIControlState.Normal)
            imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(width*i, width*j, width, width)
            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageButton)

            index++
        }
    }
    scrollView.contentSize.height = (width)*numHeight
```

Comment: Don't post code image here. paste your code in your question.

Comment: Ok will fix this, thanks

Comment: `imageButton` is `nil` because you never assigned a value to it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are creating Image from Image again.

Just do it like

```
imageButton.setImage(images[index],forState:UIControlState.Normal)
```

Hope it will work.

Or you can do it like :

```
var images = [String]?
```

in `viewDidLoad`

```
images = ["image1.png","image2.png"]
let img : UIImage = UIImage(named: images[index])!
imageButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)//Set your own frame
imageButton.setImage(img,forState:UIControlState.Normal)
```

And check for the image it must be available in your project

Answer (score 1):

The image needs to be in Assets.xcassets as an image set...works v.smooth!

Comment: Hmm. I did not need to put my images into the xcassets. I will do that eventually.